# Flutter: Move to a new screen without providing navigate back to previous screen

Tags: flutter, navigation, screen, navigator

I'm implementing an authentication flow in my Flutter app.

After a sign in attempt, the CheckAuth *(which checks whether a user is signed in or not and then opens home screen or sign up screen accordingly)* is opened with this code:

```
  void _signIn() async {
    await _auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _userEmail.trim(), password: _userPassword.trim())
        .then((task) {
      // go to home screen
      if (task.getIdToken() != null) {
        setState(() {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => new CheckAuth()));
        });
      } else {
        print("Authentication failed");
      }
    });
  }
```

Problem: I can successfully sign in to the app, but if I tap back button after I sign in, it goes back to the sign in screen (while I expect it to exit from the app).

Question: **How to move from one screen to another in Flutter without the way back?**

Do I need to somehow delete the navigator history? Or don't use navigator at all? I tried *Navigator.replace* method, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Is the sign-in screen the default route in your app?

Comment: Navigator.pushReplacement() is working perfectly at my end. Can you please share the full code?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no, the default route is CheckAuth. The problem was that I had sign up screen where I had a button that pushed the sign in screen with Navigator.push. So when a user signed in and navigated back, he got back to the sign up screen. I replaced the Navigator.push with Navigator.pushReplacement, and now it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @dhuma1981 yes, you are right, .pushReplacement() works fine. The problem was that I had sign up screen where I had a button that pushed the sign in screen with Navigator.push. So when a user signed in and navigated back, he got back to the sign up screen. I replaced the Navigator.push with Navigator.pushReplacement, and now it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
                    ),
                  ); Navigator.pushReplacement() is NOT working. HomeScreen is still showing back arrow icon after redirecting from current screen to HomeScreen. any other solution? Please share.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You need to use `Navigator.pushReplacement` when *leaving* the auth screen too. Not just when redirecting to login page.

Comment: `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/route')` for named router

Comment: Thank you. Button page doesn't back to home when we click on the bottom back button in android.

Comment: Not working in my case, displaying back arrow on Dashboard screen. I am using this code on login screen: Navigator.of(context).poppushReplacementNamed(DashboardScreen.routeName);

Comment: Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
                    ),
                  ); Navigator.pushReplacement() is NOT working. HomeScreen is still showing back arrow icon after redirecting from current screen to HomeScreen. any other solution? Please share.

Comment: Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
); Worked for me.

Comment: Some may not know how to add a router. ` return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xff089BAB),
),
      home: const Login(),
      routes: {
        "/home": (context) => const HomePage(),
        "/profile": (context) => const Profile(),
      },
    );`

Comment: In my case it was `context.pushReplacementNamed(screenName)`

Answer (score 107):

You can use the `pushAndRemoveUntil` method:

> Push the given route onto the navigator that most tightly encloses the given context, and then remove all the previous routes until the `predicate` returns true. **To remove all the routes below the pushed route, use a [RoutePredicate] that always returns false** (e.g. `(Route<dynamic> route) => false`).

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```

Comment: For some odd reason, from `SplashScreen` `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed` was not working (aka leading back button in the target screen's `AppBar`), but absolutely identical call from different screen did work. 

Your solution works in both cases, weird. Thanks!

Comment: This is better than the other answers because even if you have multiple routes in your stack you will still not have a back button.

Comment: Thanks , I had the same problem and your answer helped me to solve it .. Thanks alot

Answer (score 19):

You need to use

```
Navigator
    .of(_context)
    .pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => page));
```

Where `_context` is object of `BuildContext`
And `page` is which page you directed to.

Comment: this is not working when ever I pressed back button( assistive touch's ) route goes back to previous page

Answer (score 6):

Just simply add the below code:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/routeName', (route) => false);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you probably have already solved this. But you can set "automaticallyLeadingImplied: false" in the AppBar of the Scaffold you are navigating to.

Answer (score 5):

I have resolved this by popping from current page and showing new page:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => newPage));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution -

> Use pushAndRemoveUntil instead of pushReplacement
>
> Also, can be use **maintainState: true**

**For set root page**

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => pageName, maintainState: true),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

**For Push Page one page to another**

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => pageName,
    maintainState: false),)
```

**If you want to refresh always while appearing page then use: **

> maintainState: false

Answer (score 3):

We can use routes for the same 
Like:

```
routes: {

        LoginScreen.route_name: (_) => LoginScreen(),
        .....
      },
```

And use below code whenever you want to push and remove the backstack

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(LoginScreen.route_name);
```

**Note: Define static String inside widget LoginScreen**

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering there is a new argument that needs to be returned false   `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', (route) => false);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was not working for me because I was using the home proptery rather than initialRoute on the MaterialApp.

This is a link where there's the folloing warning which helped me to spot the error: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#2-define-the-routes

> Warning: When using initialRoute, don’t define a home property.

Answer (score -2):

if you are working with Getx state managemaent then you can try this

```html
Get.of(()=> NewPage());
```