# Flutter: Move to previous screen(2nd) and remove only previous screen (2nd 3rd 4th), not all screen (1st 2nd 3rd 4th)

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have a flow to open the apps using navigation like this:

> Profile Page(1st) -> List Attachments(2nd) -> List Resumes(3rd) -> Edit Resume(4th)

Then, from "Edit Resume(4th)" I want to go to "List Attachments(2nd)" with "remove the navigation state from 2nd 3rd 4th". So when I success navigate and open the "List Attachments(2nd)" screen, and when I click the back button from `AppBar` (in the "List Attachments(2nd)" screen) or from the device (in the "List Attachments(2nd)" screen), it will not back to "Edit Resume(4th)", but will back to "Profile Page(1st)". How to do that?

I already try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037710/flutter-move-to-a-new-screen-without-back):

```
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AttachmentsListPage(widget.userEntity)),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
```

It removes my back button on the `AppBar` in the "List Attachments(2nd)".

I also try with this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AttachmentsListPage(widget.userEntity)));
```

But still not working.

Fyi, I'm not using `route`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this using `popUntil`.

```dart
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(routeName))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this then you will have to return true where you want to stop rather than return always false.

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AttachmentsListPage(widget.userEntity)),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => route is ProfilePage,
    );
```

Another thing you can do is, call

```
Navigator.pop(context); //will return to the previous screen
Navigator.pop(context); //will return to two screens before
```

And you can use this as many times you need to go back to.

Comment: `isThisRouteYouWantToStop` is `AttachmentsListPage(widget.userEntity)` ?

Comment: Remember, it will pop all the routes until it becomes true and then it will put the route which is AttachmentsListPage on top of it.

Comment: Or you can also use PopUntil which will remove the all the routes only until it reaches the route you will give it to

Comment: I try with number 1, still not work. If it's `true` the back button and the state is not removed, if it's `false` the back button and state are removed. But I tried a number 2, it's working. So, that's the best practice to do that? or have any option?

Comment: No, pushAndRemoveUntiland popUntill are better

Comment: You should use NamedRoutes instead of the normal Route you use. Without NamedRoute it becomes very hard to handle bigger projects. and in the logic, (Route<dynamic> route) => route is ProfilePage use this

Answer (score 0):

try using this to move to the second page (set the route name).

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => SecondPage(),
    settings: RouteSettings(name: '/second'),
  ),
);
```

then on the fourth page use this to try to return to the second page without losing the second page state if not found then return to the main page (initial route).

```dart
Navigator.popUntil(
  context,
  (Route route) {
    String name = route.settings.name;
    bool secondPage = name == '/second';
    bool initPage = name == '/';
    return !initPage ? secondPage : initPage;
  },
);
```

and [this](https://i.imgur.com/Yu3jy1H.mp4) is the result.