# Fade in effect with disabled back navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-animation

I want to make a transition from one widget to another while disabling the possibility to come back (login screen).

#### Disabling back navigation

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037710/flutter-move-to-a-new-screen-without-providing-navigate-back-to-previous-screen) it is explained how to prevent navigation back:

```
 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnyWidget()),
                            (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                      );
```

#### Found a tutorial where it is remarkably well explained how to make a transition:

```
class FadeRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;

  FadeRoute({required this.page})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) =>
    page,
    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 3 ),
    transitionsBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child,
        ) =>
        Container(color: Colors.white, child: FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: child,
        )),
  );
}
```

And call:

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(FadeRoute(page: AnyWidget()));
```

---

#### Combining both

Now my question: How can I combine `pushAndRemoveUntil` with `transitionsBuilder` ?

Many thanks in advance!