# Push navigator Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

if I have an app and open 2 pages with push navigator, is there any way to open the 3rd page in order to delete the second one (and the first page remain)?

I don't know if it went well to understand my doubt

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to navigate to the next screen without the way back.

You can refer to the question, [Move to a new screen without providing navigate back to previous screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037710/flutter-move-to-a-new-screen-without-providing-navigate-back-to-previous-screen) and use `Navigator.pushReplacement`